# Помогите с регуляркой на C#!

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка, вот она:

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})<script type=\"text\/javascript\">document\.write\(\"<font class=\w*>:<\\\/font>\"\+\(\w*\^\w*\)\+\(\w*\^\w*\)\+\(\w*\^\w*\)\+\(\w*\^\w*\)\)<\/script><font class=\"\w*\">:<\/font>(\w*)<\/font
```

Когда я её засунул в VS, нажав кнопку `Escape pasted text?`, у меня получилась такая регулярка:

```
(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})<script type=\\\"text\\/javascript\\\">document\\.write\\(\\\"<font class=\\w*>:<\\\\\\/font>\\\"\\+\\(\\w*\\^\\w*\\)\\+\\(\\w*\\^\\w*\\)\\+\\(\\w*\\^\\w*\\)\\+\\(\\w*\\^\\w*\\)\\)<\\/script><font class=\\\"\\w*\\\">:<\\/font>(\\w*)<\\/font
```

В [тестере](https://regex101.com/r/n0MFtH/1) всё отлично работало, но в коде первый вариант падал с `нераспознанная escape-последовательность`, а второй не находил не одного `Match`... 
Поэтому обращаюсь за помощью)

Comment: Покажите код, который падает, ошибка в коде. И парсить HTML регулярками - это лёгкий изврат. Вот [примеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlagilitypack), как парсить.

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack не подходит, **я не тупой**. В сайте защита от парсинга посредством `<script>document.write(base64.decode("0JzQndCe0JPQniDQotCQ0JrQmNClINCt0JvQldCc0JXQndCi0J7Qkiwg0J3QlSDQntCU0JjQnSE="))</script>`.

 Обхожу через  `Selenium` и `Selenium.SourceHtml`

Comment: Еще как альтернативу `HtmlAgiltyPack` можете рассмотреть `AngleSharp`, он имеет расширение, которое умеет запускать JS скрипты и применять их к исходному HTML. Либо с помощью того же `HtmlAgilityPack` выбирайте все скрипты, а уже сами скрипты можно распарсить регулярками и достать из них `Base64`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам поможет [*verbatim string literal*](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

```cs
string pattern = @"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})<script type=\""text\/javascript\"">document\.write\(\""<font class=\w*>:<\\\/font>\""\+\(\w*\^\w*\)\+\(\w*\^\w*\)\+\(\w*\^\w*\)\+\(\w*\^\w*\)\)<\/script><font class=\""\w*\"">:<\/font>(\w*)<\/font";
```

Экранирование кавычек здесь делается через двойные кавычки `""`, остальное не надо экранировать.

---

*А то что Base64 не раскодировать в C# - [впервые слышу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743162/12888024).*

```cs
string base64 = "0JzQndCe0JPQniDQotCQ0JrQmNClINCt0JvQldCc0JXQndCi0J7Qkiwg0J3QlSDQntCU0JjQnSE=";
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(base64));
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Вывод

```
МНОГО ТАКИХ ЭЛЕМЕНТОВ, НЕ ОДИН!
```